# LibGDX - Create Animation

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx

Hello StackOverflow community!

I have been working on a game project and have recently run into an error in my Spritesheet class.

Problem: The game is developed in LibGDX which has a built-in feature that lets you split apart an image into a 2D array with the first dimension being the row and the second being the column.

E.g: spriteSheet[0][1] would give you the second column of the first row.

So I came up with a little method to generate animations using the row but when I run the game, the animation doesn't seem to work as the player remains static the whole time!

There are 4 classes involved in this process:

The Player class:

```
package com.darkbyte.games.tfa.game.entity.entities;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.darkbyte.games.tfa.game.entity.Entity;
import com.darkbyte.games.tfa.game.entity.SpriteSheet;
import com.darkbyte.games.tfa.render.RenderManager;

public class Player extends Entity {

    //The constructor for the player class
    public Player(String name, SpriteSheet spriteSheet) {
        super(name, spriteSheet);
        direction = Direction.DOWN;
    }

    //A flag to see if the player is moving
    private boolean isMoving;
    //The player's walking animations
    private Animation[] walkAnimations = {
            spriteSheet.getAnimation(4, 1/16f),
            spriteSheet.getAnimation(5, 1/16f),
            spriteSheet.getAnimation(6, 1/16f),
            spriteSheet.getAnimation(7, 1/16f)
    };
    //The player's static frames
    private TextureRegion[] staticFrames = {
            spriteSheet.getTexture(4, 0),
            spriteSheet.getTexture(5, 0),
            spriteSheet.getTexture(6, 0),
            spriteSheet.getTexture(7, 0)
    };

    //The render code for the player
    @Override
    public void render() {
        //Gets the player's direction, if the player's moving, it sets the current frame to the frame that would be played at the current moment based on the state time
        //If the player isn't moving, it sets the current frame to the static frame associated to the direction
        switch(direction) {
        case UP:
            if(isMoving)
                currentFrame = walkAnimations[0].getKeyFrame(RenderManager.getStateTime(), true);
            else
                currentFrame = staticFrames[0];
            break;
        case LEFT:
            if(isMoving)
                currentFrame = walkAnimations[1].getKeyFrame(RenderManager.getStateTime(), true);
            else
                currentFrame = staticFrames[1];
            break;
        case DOWN:
            if(isMoving)
                currentFrame = walkAnimations[2].getKeyFrame(RenderManager.getStateTime(), true);
            else
                currentFrame = staticFrames[2];
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            if(isMoving)
                currentFrame = walkAnimations[3].getKeyFrame(RenderManager.getStateTime(), true);
            else
                currentFrame = staticFrames[3];
            break;
        }
    }

    //The tick code for the player
    @Override
    public void tick() {
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)) {
            direction = Direction.UP;
            y += 2;
        } else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) {
            direction = Direction.LEFT;
            x -= 2;
        } else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN)) {
            direction = Direction.DOWN;
            y -= 2;
        } else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) {
            direction = Direction.RIGHT;
            x += 2;
        } else {

        }
    }

    //Returns if the player is moving
    public boolean isMoving() {
        return isMoving;
    }
}
```

The RenderManager class:

```
package com.darkbyte.games.tfa.render;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.darkbyte.ammarlib.files.DataWriter;
import com.darkbyte.games.tfa.Core;
import com.darkbyte.games.tfa.music.MusicManager;
import com.darkbyte.games.tfa.screens.ScreenManager;
import com.darkbyte.games.tfa.screens.UnidentifiedScreenStateException;

public class RenderManager {

    //timeSinceLastFramesPerSecondCheck is used to store the clock time since the last frames per second check was done
    private static long timeSinceLastFramesPerSecondCheck;
    //framesPassed is used to store the number of frames passed in a second
    private static int framesPassed, framesPerSecond;
    //The variable that stores the current state time of the render, used for animations
    private static float stateTime;

    //Initialisation for everything render related
    public static void init() {
        Camera.init();
        Batch.init();
        Button.init();
    }

    //Disposal for everything render related
    public static void dispose() {
        Batch.dispose();
        Button.dispose();
    }

    //The main render method
    public static void render() {
        //Gets the current clock time in milliseconds
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Increments the frames passed
        framesPassed++;

        //Updates the state time variable
        stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        //Checks if 1 second has passed since the last frames per second check
        if(now >= timeSinceLastFramesPerSecondCheck + 1000) {
            //The frames per second is set to the frames passed that second
            framesPerSecond = framesPassed;
            //The frames passed is reset
            framesPassed = 0;
            //Sets the time since the last frames per second check to now
            timeSinceLastFramesPerSecondCheck = now;
        }

        //Clears the screen from the previous render call
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //Renders the correct screen from the screen manager and plays the music for that screen
        try {
            ScreenManager.renderScreen();
            MusicManager.playMusic();
        } catch (UnidentifiedScreenStateException e) { //If the screen state runs into an error
            //Prints the error log to a time-stamped file
            DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(); //Creates a new data writer to write to the file
            writer.openFile(Core.getTime(true) + ".txt"); //Opens a the file
            writer.write("Tetros: First Age - An error has occurred!\nType: UnidentifiedScreenStateException in RenderManager!"); //Writes some basic data about the error
            writer.write(e.getMessage()); //Prints a detailed error log from the exception
            writer.closeFile(); //Closes the file, housekeeping reasons

            e.printStackTrace(); //Prints the error log to the console
            //Shows the client an error message in a dialog box
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An unexpected error occured: UnidentifiedScreenStateException in RenderManager!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            //Closes the game
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    //Returns the ticks per second rate
    public static int getFPS() {
        return framesPerSecond;
    }

    //Returns the frames passed
    public static int getFramesPassed() {
        return framesPassed;
    }

    //Returns the current state time
    public static float getStateTime() {
        return stateTime;
    }
}
```

The SpriteSheet class:

```
package com.darkbyte.games.tfa.game.entity;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.*;

public class SpriteSheet {

    //All the frames from the entity
    private TextureRegion[][] textureSheet;

    //Gets the sprite sheet for the entity and splits it into frames
    public SpriteSheet(Texture spriteSheet, int tileWidth, int tileHeight) {
        //Splits the textures into a two dimensional array
        /*
         * Dimension 1: Row
         * Dimension 2: Column
         * Example:
         * ********
         * ****0***
         * ********
         * ********
         * 0 = textureSheet[1][4] to access the second row and the fifth column
         * Some of the columns may be blank, check the sprite sheet to reference
         */
        textureSheet = TextureRegion.split(spriteSheet, tileWidth, tileHeight);
    }

    //Disposes of the textures by looping through the rows then the individual columns and disposing of all the textures
    public void dispose() {
        for(TextureRegion[] textureRow : textureSheet) for(TextureRegion texture : textureRow) texture.getTexture().dispose();
    }

    //Returns the texture at a certain row or column (starting at 1,1 being textureSheet[0][0])
    public TextureRegion getTexture(int row, int column) {
        return textureSheet[row][column];
    }

    //Returns an animation using pieces of the sprite sheet
    public Animation getAnimation(int row, float animationFPS) {

        //Returns the animation generated using the frames from the row specified and the FPS from the parameters
        return new Animation(animationFPS, textureSheet[row]);
    }
}
```

The TestRoom class:

```
package com.darkbyte.games.tfa.game.world.room.rooms;

import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.darkbyte.games.tfa.game.entity.Entity;
import com.darkbyte.games.tfa.game.entity.EntityManager;
import com.darkbyte.games.tfa.game.world.room.Room;
import com.darkbyte.games.tfa.render.Batch;
import com.darkbyte.games.tfa.render.Camera;

public class TestRoom extends Room {

    //Initialises the room's tiled map and map renderer
    @Override
    public void init() {
        this.tileMap = Room.generateMap("assets/world/rooms/test.tmx");
        this.mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(this.tileMap);

        entitiesInRoom.add(EntityManager.getPlayer(0, 0, 0));
    }

    //Disposes of the room
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        this.tileMap.dispose();
    }

    //Runs the render code for the room
    @Override
    public void render() {
        //Sets the map renderer's viewpoint to the viewpoint of the camera
        mapRenderer.setView(Camera.getCamera());
        //Renders the map
        mapRenderer.render();

        //Begins the drawing batch
        Batch.getGameBatch().begin();
        //Loops through the entities in the room and renders them
        for(Entity entityToRender : entitiesInRoom) {
            entityToRender.render();
            Batch.getGameBatch().draw(entityToRender.getCurrentFrame(), entityToRender.getX(), entityToRender.getY());
        }
        //Ends the drawing batch
        Batch.getGameBatch().end();
    }

    //Runs the tick code for the room
    @Override
    public void tick() {
        //Loops through the entities in the room and runs their tick code
        for(Entity entityToRender : entitiesInRoom) entityToRender.tick();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to re-invent the wheel with your SpriteSheet class. Trying to manually create your sprite sheet and pick out your animations like that is going to explode into an unmanageable amount of work as you add other sprites or if you ever want to tweak anything, such as number of frames in an animation. Use TexturePacker and TextureAtlas. (see libgdx documentation)

Comment: @Tenfour04 It's actually saved me quite a bit of time so far but thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of building all the animation mechanism yourself, you should use the Libgdx's Animation, which is much easier to use. Read the [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation).

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find what I was looking for before on the old Google documentation but the new wiki is a real help :)